# Hardware firewall for Linux web (and mail) server allows UDP connections to any local port from remote ports 53 and 123 -- is this safe?

Tags: linux, firewall, port

I'm trying to tighten security on a linux web server. It has a hardware firewall with a default rule set and I noticed two rules that concern me:

```
remote port: 123; local port: ANY; protocol: UDP; action: ALLOW

remote port: 53; local port: ANY; protocol: UDP; action: ALLOW
```

These were part of the server provider's default rule set for a linux web & mail server but I'm questioning it because it appears that it allows connections to ALL ports on the server if the attacker simply uses the protocol UDP and does it from either port 53 or port 123 on his end.

I tried to research it and I'm still puzzled. Is it safe to remove these rules (will that affect the operation of the server) or if they're left open does it make the server very vulnerable since it apparently allows UDP connections to all ports on the server?

Comment: Are you sure these rules are for *incoming* connections, not *outgoing* connections?  Those are totally valid rules for a network with fairly tight access controls to the Internet.

Comment: Yoonix, thanks for the response.  Here are the exact rules in the firewall:

Comment: Remote IP: All Remote Port: 123  Local Port: Any Protocol: UDP  Action: Allow Status: Active
Remote IP: All Remote Port: 53  Local Port: Any  Protocol: UDP  Action: Allow  Status: Active

Comment: I assume that means it would allow incoming connections on all ports if it's UDP and the remote ports are 53 or 123.  Is this standard, and safe?

Comment: Right.  First off, UDP has no concept of 'connections'. It's a stateless protocol.  The way I read it is that this would be allowing **replies** for external DNS and NTP queries.  The queries may originate from any *local* port, but the replies will most definitely be coming from the stated *remote* ports of 53 (dns) and 123 (ntp).  The firewall still protects you from random probes on the Internet because you have no port forwarding defined and you're likely using NAT.  The firewall wouldn't know where to send the packets if a local system didn't originate a request.

Answer (score 0):

UDP 53 is used for DNS and UDP 123 is used for NTP. I would say it is save to remove these if you do not need access from outside to these services.

I would even advice blocking port `123` as there are problems with older NTP servers which sometimes leads them to being used in DDoS attacks.

Comment: Thanks edvinas can you clarify what you mean "if you do not need access from outside"?  We don't have physical access to the server; we have to connect to it with SSH and SFTP.  Isn't that accessing it from outside (in which case we should not remove those rules)?  And I still don't understand why those rules allow connections to all ports on the server.  Please pardon me just trying to understand and have confidence about it.

Comment: I ment DNS and NTP service access from outside. Sorry for not making it clear ;)

Comment: And I would even advice to block port 123 as there are too many vulnerable NTP servers in the wild which are being used for DDoS.

Comment: Okay thanks, though pardon me I'm still a little clueless about whether or not I need "DNS and NTP service access from outside".  It's simply a linux web and mail server, and we administrate it remotely via SSH and SFTP.  What do you think?

Answer (score 0):

Most firewall rules have a direction they are applied to and these two rules are likely for packets leaving not packets coming in. So they likely just allow outbound DNS (port 53) and NTP (port 123) packets.

Most firewalls track some state information and will then allow response packets back from the same remote IP:port to the local IP:port.

```
localsystem:13321 --> DNS packet to ---> remote system:53
remote system:53 --> DNS reply to ---> 192.168.5.5:13321
```

Comment: Thanks Brian, but honestly, really and truly, the web-based control panel for this hardwire firewall simply has the following settings for each rule:

Comment: Remote IP, Protocol, Remote Port, Local Port, Action (allow/deny), and Status (Activate/Deactivate)

Comment: Some separate OUTBOUND rules form INBOUND rules on different configuration screens along with a choice of default action (allow or deny). Never seen one that has one set of rules with no direction indicated.

Comment: Firewall rules generally *don't* have directionality. Rather, they're applied to a specific interface, and the rules apply to any packets entering that interface.

Comment: Most have rule chains that are applied at different points in the traffic handling process, the main two being receiving and sending a packet which can both apply to the same interface. There are a lot of different implementations however so it is hard to use exact terms.